# How do I get historical foreign exchange data on an hourly basis?

Tags: r

My code works. However, I'm receiving the output for each day. I wanted it to give me data for all business hours

```
library(priceR)

cur <- historical_exchange_rates("CAD", to = "USD",
                                 start_date = "2010-01-01", end_date = "2021-08-29")

print (cur)

 date one_CAD_equivalent_to_x_USD
1   2010-01-01                    0.956718
2   2010-01-02                    0.956718
3   2010-01-03                    0.956718
4   2010-01-04                    0.960639
5   2010-01-05                    0.962288
```

I want the output to show date, time and the rate

```
date        BH       conversion(CAD to USD)
2010-01-01  9:00:00   0.956718
```

Comment: I think the `priceR` package just doesn't do this. I don't even know if the hourly data are available from [its data source](https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/curConverter.do).  A little digging suggests that [it's not](https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/browseExplanation.do?node=1495). I would try asking on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: @BenBolker hey just to clarify. do you mean the ECB doesnt give data on hourly exchange rate fluctuations? its just daily?

Comment: The link in my comment above goes to a page where they say that the data periods are "Daily, monthly, quarterly, annual". It's always possible that the hourly exchange rate data are available from them *somehow*, but that's as far as I got when looking.